# Debug VS2010 website at root instead of subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

So I inherited an IIS website and I am not familiar with the tools. When I run project it wants to start up at localhost/myApp/. If I do not have IIS configured to start up in this location then debugger fails to attach. However, I have code that assumes my site is on the root directory. I am on IIS 7 and Win 7 x64.

when I debug the website from inside VS2010 how do I tell it that my website is located at localhost/? My project is the one highlighted in red.

[image]
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you can't change the starting url is because of the way the project was added to the solution.  When the Web Site project is listed as a url instead of as a local file system path, it is because the project was added to the solution by using `Add > Existing Web Site > Local IIS` option.  When a project is added in this manner, then Visual Studio.NET will not allow you to change the path.

In order to change the path, you should remove the project from your solution and add it back to the solution using `Add > Existing Web Site > File System`.  Use the Add Existing Web Site dialog to navigate to the project folder (the same folder that is used as the Physical Path for the site in IIS).  When the project is readded it will be listed in the Solution Explorer by the local path (i.e., E:\inetput\myapp) instead of the localhost url.  From there, all of the options under Start Options should be configurable.

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner. I had given up hope. So this is what I did. Step 1. Remove existing site as suggested. Step 2. Add file system site pointing to my websites directory root. Step 3. Change IIS configuration so that the solution directory was also my websites directory root. Step 4. RMB my new website project and choose 'Property Pages.' Step 5. Under Start Options enable "Use custom server" and set it to http://localhost. Now when I run my project it starts up and breakpoints can be debugged. Thank-You!

Answer (score 10):

To debug the website using root with visual studio in a website project do the following:

1. Push F4 to bring up the properties window.
2. Change the Virtual Path to '/' and then your good to go.

Comment: This only seems to work for me if I have the site running in the debugger. If the site is not running I don't see the Virtual Path property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch  your solution to use local IIS instead of the in-memory ASP.NET Development server

- In the .sln, right click the project for your web app, select **Properties**
- Select the **Web** tab
- In the "servers" section you'll have 3 options.
- Select "**Use Local IIS Web Server**"

Then you can modify hosting properties such as the url

- On the same tab, you'll now have two options which can get you where you need to be
- Project URL
- Override Application root URL

Comment: I can't find the Web tab. Maybe I don't have a web app? Under my solution I have http://localhost/myWebSite . I right click it and I have Properties Window and Property Pages. Neither of these have a "web tab." ???

Comment: It may not think its a webapp.  Anyway you can screenshot the solution window in VS and post it somewhere?

Comment: Good idea. Done. The line marked in red is the project assigned to me.

Comment: thanks, Try right clicking on the C# project, the last one in the list.  The others are referencing the sites configured in IIS already.  You're wanting to basically put this code in a new/modified location which the C# project (.csproj) should give you

Comment: way to stick with me. I went to that screen, but still don't see anything related to changing the directory. I uploaded a screenshot. How is it this hard to tell IIS where my website lives? *pulls out some hair*

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your web project file
2. Select properties
3. Select the web tab (from the tabs on
   the left) half way down there is a
   section called servers there you can
   customise the web server you are
   using and the URL it should be
   directed to when you start
   debugging.

Comment: I am not seeing these settings. In my solution explorer I have my solution, underneath several projects. Right clicking on my relevant project and selecting properties shows the properties panel. There is an "opened url" parameter, but it cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are working with an ASP.Net Web Site as opposed to an ASP.Net Web Application?

If you have a folder called "App_Code" then it's a Web Site and will have fewer options.

Intro to Web Application Projects (has an info table):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(v=vs.80).aspx

Might help you migrate if it is a Web Site and you want more control:

http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I can't migrate because the project is in TFS. I only update a small part of the system. The rest is managed by other team members. I did ask about how to get this setup on my system, but nobody knew how. Apparently the old dev just made do with the inconveniences.

Comment: Hmm... in that case you may want to consider refactoring your code to eliminate the assumption of being at the root web app.  Maybe look into making the root app path configurable?  You could put it in applicationSettings in your web config (key words for easy search).

Answer (score 0):

I've now had to do this often enough that I thought I would add more explicit steps. These are based off of the accepted answer from rsbarro. Steps are for VS2010

1. Right-click on existing website and choose **Remove**
2. Right-click on the solution and choose **Add | Existing Website | Choose folder**
3. Right-click on new item in solution explorer and choose **Property Pages**
4. Under Start Options tick **Custom Server** and enter **`http://localhost`**
5. Right-click on new item in solution explorer and choose **Set as Startup Project**